# MongoDB URI Heroku config vars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I am building a MERN stack app and have pushed the node/express backend to Heroku. To get the URI I am using Heroku config vars, but I just get an error. I have configured the config var on Heroku like this:

`MONGODB_URI: mongodb+srv://user:password@cluser/collection`

NB this is not the actual URI just for demonstration. So that's not the error

Sever.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const atlas_uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
// The line above crates the error.
const staticFiles = './routes/public';

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose
  .connect(atlas_uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(
    () => console.log('Database sucsesfully connected'),
    err => console.error(`Could nor connect to database: ${err}`)
  );

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, staticFiles + '/index.html'));
});

app.use('/api/posts', require('./routes/api/posts'));

// 404
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, staticFiles + '/404.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`));
```

Error log

```
17:33:31 web.1   |  > server@ start C:\Users\chris\Documents\Projects\forum-mern\server
17:33:31 web.1   |  > node ./build/main.bundle.js
17:33:31 web.1   |  C:\Users\chris\Documents\Projects\forum-mern\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:579
17:33:31 web.1   |      throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
17:33:31 web.1   |      ^
17:33:31 web.1   |  Error [MongooseError]: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
17:33:31 web.1   |      at new MongooseError (C:\Users\chris\Documents\Projects\forum-mern\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\mongooseError.js:10:11)
17:33:31 web.1   |      at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\chris\Documents\Projects\forum-mern\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:579:11)
17:33:31 web.1   |      at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\chris\Documents\Projects\forum-mern\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:333:15)
17:33:31 web.1   |      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\chris\Documents\Projects\forum-mern\server\build\main.bundle.js:1:2842)
17:33:31 web.1   |      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\chris\Documents\Projects\forum-mern\server\build\main.bundle.js:1:3252)
17:33:31 web.1   |      at n (C:\Users\chris\Documents\Projects\forum-mern\server\build\main.bundle.js:1:110)
17:33:31 web.1   |      at C:\Users\chris\Documents\Projects\forum-mern\server\build\main.bundle.js:1:902
17:33:31 web.1   |      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\chris\Documents\Projects\forum-mern\server\build\main.bundle.js:1:911)
17:33:31 web.1   |      at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1185:30)
17:33:31 web.1   |      at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1205:10)
17:33:31 web.1   |      at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1034:32)
17:33:31 web.1   |      at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:14)
17:33:31 web.1   |      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
17:33:31 web.1   |      at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
17:33:31 web.1   |  npm
17:33:31 web.1   |   ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
17:33:31 web.1   |  npm ERR! errno 1
17:33:31 web.1   |  npm
17:33:31 web.1   |  ERR! server@ start: `node ./build/main.bundle.js`
17:33:31 web.1   |  npm ERR! Exit status 1
17:33:31 web.1   |  npm ERR!
17:33:31 web.1   |  npm ERR! Failed at the server@ start script.
17:33:31 web.1   |  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
17:33:31 web.1   |  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
17:33:31 web.1   |  npm ERR!     C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-16T15_33_31_711Z-debug.log
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
17:33:31 web.1   Exited with exit code null
```

### Update #1

The application work when the exact same URI is locally in the project. The problem occurs when the URI is on Heroku in a config var. I have followed the documentation on Heroku on how to use Config Vars. I get the same error when the URI is wrapped in quotes and when it is not

### Update #2

The Problem was a mixture of Webpack and testing Heroku locally. When using the non-bundles files and running on a remote server it worked like a charm.

Comment: The issue isn't with connecting to the database, it looks like `atlas_uri` is undefined. If you `console.log(atlas_uri)` immediately after defining it, it should be undefined. Check that you have actually set the environment variable correctly.

Comment: You can test that the string works by **temporarily** copying it into your application rather than trying to import from an environment variable.

Comment: I think you need to add the variable MONGODB_URI to Heroku like this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard